# Check if there is a duplicate letter within a string regardless of lowercase or uppercase

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

```
public static boolean check(String input) {
    Set<Character> tmp = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch) && !tmp.add(ch)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am quite new to programming and i found a way to find a duplicate letter within a string but how would i be able to return true if the duplicate letter was a capital or non-capital for example "Aa".

Answer (score 1):

Change the `input` to Lowercase before the for loop.

```
public static boolean check(String input) {
    Set<Character> tmp = new HashSet<Character>();
    // This will make all capital letters lowercase but will not change the original string
    String testInput = input.toLowerCase();
    for(char ch : testInput.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(ch) && !tmp.add(ch)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry i dont get what you mean.

Comment: @AranRassull - I've updated the answer to include the code. Let me know if you need an explanation as to why this works.